# Get string from standard input

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have a command line application called "MyApp.exe", that I want to use like this:

```
DoSomething|MyApp.exe
```

That is, `DoSomething` outputs a string to standard out, and then the pipe sends it as standard in to MyApp.exe.

How can I accept this string in MyApp.exe?

UPD.

And what if I want to test this?
I'm using public methods to start my application activity:

```
using (MyApp app = new MyApp())
{ 
 result = app.Run(args);
}
If(result!=0) Assert.Fail("Failed");
```

I.e. I need to write some data into input stream before execute Run()

Comment: Re testing - If Console.Write doesn't work, I think you'll need to write another app to start a new `Process` of MyApp, and then write to its `.StandardInput` stream.  Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Console.In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.in.aspx) to access stdin.

Or `Console.ReadLine()` which is just a shortcut for `Console.In.ReadLine()`.

Comment: Or just `Console.ReadLine()` (if it's text).

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Now a new question: How can I imitate the standard input in tests?

Answer (score 1):

`Console.ReadLine()`  is used to read the Input